# setInterval / setTimeout issue in iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, settimeout, setinterval

I builded a basic avoider game. When I run the game in iOS, I'm having a problem with setInterval or setTimeout (i've tried both). Strange thing is that it works fine as a .swf, or an .apk, but not in iOS. I found that the problem has something to do with the setTimeout/setInterval.

I have a document class which controls what's being displayed, like, tutorial, level 1 screen, level up screen, etc. It goes like this:

```
public function DocumentClass() 
{
    menuScreen = new MenuScreen();
    menuScreen.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.START, onRequestStart);
    menuScreen.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.CREDI, onRequestCredits);
    addChild(menuScreen);                   
} 
public function onRequestStart(navigationEvent:NavigationEvent):void
{
    tut = new Tutorial();
    tut.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.NEXT, onRequestNext);
    addChild(tut);
    menuScreen.removeEventListener(NavigationEvent.START, onRequestStart);
    menuScreen.removeEventListener(NavigationEvent.CREDI, onRequestCredits);
    removeChild(menuScreen);
    menuScreen = null;
}
```

It goes always like this, removing the last screen and the listeners, and popping up the new screen, for a different level or an info screen.

In the class that I've found the bug, I'm using a Timer, mostly for interaction purposes and enemy generation.
Something like this:

```
public function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
{
    if ( Math.random() < 0.02 ){
        enemySpot();
    }
}

public function enemySpot()
{ 
    var enemySpot = new EnemySpot(posX[incDec], posY[incDec])
    spots.push(enemySpot);
    addChild(enemySpot);
    enemyBorn = setTimeout(enemyGenerator, 1000);
}

public function enemyGenerator()
{
    enemy = new Enemy(posX[incDec], posY[incDec])
    army.push(enemy);
    addChild(enemy);
    removeEnemy = setTimeout(enemyRemoval, 6000);
    incDec = incDec + 1;
    clearTimeout(enemyBorn);
}

public function enemyRemoval()
{
    for each (var elem:Bola in army)
    {
        removeChild(elem);
        elem = null;
        army.reverse();
        army.pop();
        army.reverse();
        clearTimeout(removeEnemy);
        break
    }
}
```

It works fine until the player hits the enemies.

```
if (avatarHasBeenHit)
{
    avatar.alpha = 0;
    avatar.stopDrag();
    if (bol2)
    {
        aDeath = new avatarDeath();//just an animation, of the avatar dyeing 
        addChild(aDeath);
        aDeath.x = avatar.x;
        aDeath.y = avatar.y;
        uniTimer1 = getTimer();
        bol2 = false;
    }
    goNext = setInterval(leaveScreen,1500);
}
public function leaveScreen()
{
    gameTimer.stop();
    dispatchEvent(new AvatarEvent(AvatarEvent.DEAD));
    clearInterval(goNext);
}
```

Once the player hits an enemy, the game stops generating enemies on the next levels, which are in different class files. It goes like this:
Avatar hits Enemy -> dispatch AvatarEvent.DEAD; DocumentClass removes the Level Screen child, and deploys the child with the next Level Screen, that have the same structure as the previous level, somehow the setTimeout won run, so no new enemies. But it works fine on the swf and apk files! Any idea of whats causing the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never used setTimeout on iOS so I can't confirm if it's a bug or limitation to the software, but if you're really stuck you could use a `Timer` instead, I have used the Timer class on iOS before.

Comment: i have use setTimeout it works fine, simple but effective

Comment: Probably mixing Timer and setTimeout/setInterval cause some kind of bug in iOS. I can truly conclude that, cause this is my first try with iOS. Anyway I fixed this by using only the Timer + getTimer(), avoiding any kind of intervals/timeouts. Thanks for your hints

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it has something to do with you calling `clearTimeout()`. Please consider that when a `setTimeout()` is completed and the relevant function is called, the handle returned by it, is no longer valid. So possibly when you use `clearTimeout(enemyBorn)` you are actually clearing the timeout for `removeEnemy` (same for the other `clearTimeout`).

Comment: I also try without the clearTimeout, the thing is that the code works fine in a swf, and in android, but not in iOS. I solve it by removing the intervals/timeouts and use only the Timer, with getTimer(). Somehow using the Timer and the intervals were messing up my app. Thanks for your help!